# Microsoft Mediaroom Application framework - TV Ticker control font issue

Tags: .net, iptv, mediaroom

The  TV Ticker control displays the contents  as small and very blurry in Television (not legible and readable). Increasing the font size is not helping, it renders the contents with same lesser quality with bigger font. We are using ADK3.3  & STB version  2.3.28673.832.  The issue is observed only in TV and not in simulator.

The following configuration are used:

- TV Page resolution  - Width 1280px    height 720px
- TV ticker – A TV label is used as child control to display the content & it is configured with font style reg18.

We also observed if the width and height of TV page is not configured the contents are rendered properly  and it is very clear.  However configuring the above height & width brings back the issue.

Comment: Is this the same MediaRoom product that Microsoft sold to Ericsson in April 2013? Are you using the .Net framework (per your tags)?

Comment: Yes for both questions

Comment: Where's you .NET code that's not working?

Comment: It is the part which generate the News content and set the text to TV ticker label. So posting them is not helpful. hard coded text also not working.  Mediaroom works on .NET framework.  If you can suggest on TV ticker issue it will be helpful. thx.